# How Can I make a windows to pop up from the bottom of the screen?

Tags: java, android-studio, user-interface

I have a Map, with markers on the Gas Stations around my location. When I click on them, I want a window to raise from the bottom of the screen (and go only half through the Map Screen) where I want to display info about that gas station. How do I do this window coming from the bottom of the screen? Animation?

[image]

Comment: You are looking for a bottom sheet. This may be helpful: https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom/android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarations :

```
  Animation slideup, slidedown;
  LinearLayout bottomLay;
```

Initializations:

```
  slideup = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);
  slidedown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down);
  bottomLay = findViewById(R.id.bottomLay); //your bottom view
```

start the animation :

```
public void startSlideDown() {
       bottomLay.startAnimation(slidedown); // down 
}
```

or

```
public void startSlideUp() {
      bottomLay.startAnimation(slideup);  // up
}
```

slide_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```